# How to extract an the last data from an file path php which has an <b> tag

Tags: php, regex

I am tying to retrive the last part of an path . I have an path value

```
/var/local/<b>india/aaa.php</b>-who is this
```

I need to retrive the `aaa.php-who is this` using php regex.

Comment: What's regular about your example? What can be depended on not to change? will it always be `<b>` tags? Will it always be `india/`?

Comment: it will be bold because i receive form searchengine

Comment: no it wont be always india it is dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code :** (FIXED)

```
$pattern = '/<b>[a-z\/\.\-]+\/([a-z\.\-]+)<\/b>(.+)/i';
preg_match($pattern, $path, $matches);

$result = $matches[1].$matches[2];

echo $result;
```

**Output :** (FIXED)

> aaa.php-who is this

---

**Another approach :** ('shorter', with the same result)

```
$path = str_replace("</b>","",$path);
preg_match('/.+\/(.+)/i', $path, $matches);
$result = $matches[1];
```

Comment: This extracts the data between <b> and <b/> but i need to extract data after the last slash

Answer (score 0):

Do you *have* to use regex?

If not, here is an alternative to using regex, if the path structure is always the same:

```
$path = "/var/local/<b>india/aaa.php</b>-who is this";
$lst_temp = explode('/', $path);
$url = str_replace("</b>", '', $lst_temp[3]);
```